# SQLAlchemy returning <Name1>, <Name2> values etc

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Currently exploring SQLAlchemy. Did all the proper procedures.

Python Code:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    passwd = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

What i did on the terminal:

```
>>> db.create_all()
>>> from logins import User
>>> db.session.add(User(username='admin', passwd='passwd'))
>>> db.session.add(User(username='user1', passwd='passwd'))
>>> db.commit_all()
>>> User.query.all()
**[<Name 1>, <Name 2>]**
```

The weird thing is it returns <Name 1>, <Name 2> instead of the actual values. but if i call it individually:

```
>>> User.query.filter_by(username='admin').first()
<Name 1>
>>> me = User.query.filter_by(username='admin').first()
>>> me.id
1
>>> me.username
'admin'
>>> me.passwd
'passwd'
>>>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You want to include a __repr__ function, see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html and search that page for __repr__

Comment: It works! Thanks!, Finally outputs the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

When you query.all() it gives you all the objects of the class "User" it won't give all of the classes properties. What you could do is write a show() Function within your User class:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    passwd = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

def show_info(self):
    print(self.id, self.username, self.passwd, self.date_created)
```

You can also grab all attributes of that class by querying all:

```
user_query = User.query.all()
user_ids = [user.id for user in user_query.id]
```